# Use a variable in system() and store its output in a file

Tags: c, linux, shell

I want to store output of system() in a file which uses a string variable.

```
char file[10],command[100];
printf("Enter file name:\n");
fgets(file,10,stdin);
sprintf(command,"lsof | grep %s >> result.txt",file);
system(command);
```

result.txt comes out to be empty.

Comment: `fgets` includes the `\n` character in `file`(unless the input is more than 8 characters long). Strip it out before using `sprintf`. And `command` should have enough space to accomodate all the characters.

Comment: And what is the problem you're having with that? What is your input? What is the formatted string `command`? What happens when you run it? What does [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) return? It [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) returns `-1` what it the value of `errno`? We need more details than just "it doesn't work".

Comment: Hints: I see *two* problems: First of all that `"result.txt"` is *eleven* characters (including string terminator!); The second that `fgets` might leave the newline in the string.

Comment: @user3582454 , Try `file[strcspn(file,"\n")]=0` just after the `fgets` to strip off the newline character.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , If there is no newline character, then it is the same as doing `file[strlen(file)]=0` ,i.e, overwriting the `\0` character with `\0` itself. However, if `fgets` returns `NULL`, then the result is UB.

Comment: @CoolGuy True, misread the function.

Comment: Woww that worked.. I didn't know about that. thanx a loott @Cool Guy.

Comment: 'file' is way to close to the well known type 'FILE *'  it is a bad idea to define local variables (or function names) that differ from the system names only in capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

After you enter data for

```
fgets(file,10,stdin);
```

you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. `fgets` also includes the newline character(`\n`) in the buffer(`file`) unless the input is more than 8 characters long.

To fix the problem, you need to strip off the newline character from `file` as it is the problem-maker. You can achieve this by using a cool function [`strcspn()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcspn&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) from `string.h`. Add the following just after your `fgets`:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer,"\n")] = 0;
```

or else, you could use the familiar [`strlen()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlen&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) function:

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);

if(len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
    buffer[len-1] = 0;
```

You should also check if `system()` and `fgets()` is successful by checking their return values.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(file,20,stdin);
```

should be

```
fgets(file,sizeof(file),stdin);
```

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline character